# c++ reading from file with ':' between each word

Tags: c++, file-handling

How do you read a file of the format:

```
121:yes:no:334
```

Here's my code:

```
int main(){

    string one, two;
    int three, four;

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("lol.txt");

    infile >> three;

    getline(infile, one, ':');

    getline(infile, two, ':');

    infile >> four;

    cout << three << one << two << four;
    return 0;
}
```

output: 121yes0

So it ignores the secong get line, and a 0 is somehow found.

Comment: It's probably related to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction).

Comment: please explain the meaning of "none work", include expected and actual output in the qeustion

Comment: When working with iostreams one must either enable exceptions or manually inspect / adjust stream state after invoking each method. This code silently ignores all the possible failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contents of file

```
121:yes:no:334

infile >> three;           it would input 121
getline(infile, one, ':'); it did not take input due to :
getline(infile, two, ':'); it would take yes
infile >> four;            it take none
```

so you can do somethis like

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string one, two;
    int three, four;

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("lol.txt");

    infile >> three;

    infile.ignore();

    getline(infile, one, ':');

    getline(infile, two, ':');

    infile >> four;

    cout << three << one << two << four;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after the first read, the stream looks like this

```
:yes:no:334
```

so the first `getline` will read the empty string before ":", the second will red "yes", and the last integer extraction will fail.

Use `getline` all the way and convert to integers as you go;

```
int main(){
    string token;
    ifstream infile("lol.txt");
    getline(infile, token, ':');
    int three = std::stoi(token);
    string one;
    getline(infile, one, ':');
    string two;
    getline(infile, two, ':');
    getline(infile, token, ':');
    int four = std::stoi(token);
    cout << three << one << two << four;
    return 0;
}
```

(Error handling left as an exercise.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
ifstream dataFile;
dataFile.open("file.txt");
int num1, num2;
dataFile >> num1; // read 121
dataFile.ignore(1, ':');
string yes, no;
getline(dataFile, yes, ':'); // read yes
getline(dataFile, no, ':'); // read no
dataFile >> num2; //read 334
return 0;}
```